# Swagger array of integer return type

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm just getting started with using the swagger-editor to define my RESTful API and I'm confused on the responses.  Many of my methods simply return an array of integers, and I'm not understanding how to specify that in the YAML.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The OpenAPI (fka Swagger) Specification 2.0 uses a subset of JSON Schema v4. You can refer to the [JSON Schema docs](http://json-schema.org/) or [this great guide](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/) to learn how to describe different data types using JSON Schema. But keep in mind that some features of JSON Schema are not supported or work differently in OpenAPI/Swagger. The Specification [mentions](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#schemaObject) what exactly is supported.

Back to your question, an array of integers is defined as:

```yaml
type: array
items:
  type: integer
```

Or in the context of a response:

```yaml
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: integer
```

If arrays of integers are used in multiple places in your spec, you can define the array in the global `definitions` section and then use `$ref` to refer to it:

```yaml
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ArrayOfInt"

definitions:
  ArrayOfInt:
    type: array
    items:
      type: integer
```

You can also specify `example` values for the array. Swagger UI will display this example, and some mocking tools will use it when generating sample responses.

```yaml
definitions:
  ArrayOfInt:
    type: array
    items:
      type: integer
    example: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    # Make sure to put the multi-item "example"
    # on the same level as the "type" and "items" keywords
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I'm using swagger to generate the spec based on doc comments...  Can I specify an array of integers as the response using doc comments?

Comment: @AaronHill: It should be possible, but it depends on the language/framework you're using. I'd recommend [asking a new question](/questions/ask) about your specific framework.

Comment: What is the parameter type? 
I'm not able to use array of integer with parameter type = "query" and 
`type: array
    items:
      type: integer`

Comment: @carmelolg: It's hard to say without seeing your actual API definition. Please [ask a new question](/questions/ask?tags=swagger+openapi) instead.